Can't boot VHD image after resizing in VirtualBox
I have a pretty big mess to sort.
I have a 512GB VHD which I use to store private backups. It started running out of storage so I looked online how to make it bigger (as I assumed VHD's probably just have a value that determines max size). Turns out I was totally wrong:

I opened the VHD in Virtual Media Manager
Resized it to 2TB (just to give enough room), pressed apply
Now attempting to mount in File Explorer yields the error: "Couldn't Mount File - The disk image is corrupted". Mounting thru dskmgmt yields an error stating that directories are corrupted

To add to this, the drive had BitLocker encryption. I know the passkey, but I fear this adds further complexion. After reading online, it seems that this has been an issue corrupting files for over 12 years, so I am astounded that in the modern day there isn't as much as a warning against this. Nevertheless, I am asking any of you if you had any luck in recovering files in such a scenario. These files to me are of importance, and losing them would be a significant loss.
PS. of course I should have also backed up, but consider that backing up a 512GB file isn't so straightforward.

Hello DrMoishe Pippik, I appreciate your reply. I made this request after an hour of trying but I actually found a solution! By mounting in VMWare, it updates it to a "new format". Unsure what exactly this means but it fixed my issue! Maybe it recreated some missing data? Hope this helps someone in the future :D

Since you found a remedy, why not write it up, explaining details, and make it an answer. Yes, it is acceptable to answer your own question.

Done :) added the info as an answer

Answering my own question
As stated in a comment:
I made this request after an hour of trying but I actually found a solution! By mounting in VMWare, it updates it to a "new format". Unsure what exactly this means but it fixed my issue! Maybe it recreated some missing data? Hope this helps someone in the future :D
I can't really attest to what fixed it. Currently just copying all the files into a new virtual disk. Didn't "uncorrupt" the VHD, just the files are accessible from within VMWare.
Mounting:
Used an existing Windows 10 VM, opened settings for it, Hardware > Add > Hard Disk > Recommended > Use existing disk, etc
